# Parametrizing the Paste value when using PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I was looking to have a table so that when I am copy-pasting some columns from one WorkBook to another I can modify the "Paste:=" parameter depending on my needs. To my surprise something like:

```
'The code itself work if i change paste for the regular xlPasteAll or any 
'of those, this are just the "key" lines

whichPaste = columnRaw.Offset(0, 2)  'whichPaste is defined as a String
destinySheet.range(letterMarket & firstMarketRow + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=whichPaste
```

I have seen that xlPasteAll is an `Enum` so that then I understand it doesn't work as an `String`. Shall I then just use the associated integer that has? There is not a better approach to this issue?

Thanks!

Finally what I did thanks to the accepted answer is the following:

```
whichPaste = translatePaste(whichPaste)
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=CInt(whichPaste)
```

where translatePaste is:

```
Function translatePaste(whichPaste As String) As String
    If whichPaste = "xlPasteAll" Then
        translatePaste = "-4104"
    ' more casuistics...
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the corresponding value, as found in the `xlPasteType` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype).

If your table contains specific members of the enum (e.g `xlPasteAll`, `xlPasteValues`, etc), another option might be a simple helper function, perhaps something like this:

```
Function ConvertPasteType(pasteType As String) As Integer
    Select Case pasteType
        Case "xlPasteAll"
            ConvertPasteType = xlPasteAll
        Case "xlPasteValues"
            ConvertPasteType = xlPasteValues
        ' and so on
    End Select
End Function
```

And then:

```
whichPaste = columnRaw.Offset(0, 2) 
destinySheet.range(letterMarket & firstMarketRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=ConvertPasteType(whichPaste)
```

Comment: Well is not exactly what I was looking for but it does the trick. Is just that I wanted to find if i could avoid using the value itself. In my case I did a function that translates the value since the CInt("xlPasteAll") was not working by itself since is not an Enum.